# Is there any way to justify this approximation of the solution of a rather simple equation?

Tags: approximation, nonlinear-optimization

I am considering the problem of finding the root of equation $$f(x)=-x+\sum_{i=m}^{i=n} \sqrt{x+i}=0$$ where $m,n$ can  both be from very small to very large integers. Since, in a single calculation, the equation has to be solved billions of times (high accuracy is required for the solution) , I tried to find a good approximation of the solution from which Newton's method and/or high order iteration schemes could start and solve in a minimum number of iterations.

The solution is easily bounded by $x_m$ and $x_n$ corresponding to the solutions of $$x_k=(n-m+1)\sqrt{x+k}$$ which are simple to solve but the range is quite large ($\approx (n-m-1)$ for large values of $n$) while the solution is rather close to $n^2$. For large values of $n$, using series to  $ O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right)$, the solution is more or less such that $$n^2+(2-2 m) n+\left(m^2-m+1\right)< x <n^2+(3-2 m) n+\left(m^2-2 m\right)+\frac{4-2
   m}{n}$$

To improve the guess of the solution, I wondered if I could find $\alpha(m,n)$ such that the solution of $$x=(n-m+1)\sqrt{x+\alpha(m,n)}$$ would be as close as possible to the solution. To my surprise, $\alpha(m,n)=\frac {m+n}{2}$ has been revealed to provide very good results (in spite of their cost, I also tried geometric and harmonic means of the $i$'s from $m$ to $n$ but they revealed to be much less efficient). So, the current approximation of the solution is $$x\approx \frac{1}{2} \left((n-m+1)^2+\sqrt{(n-m+1)^2 \left((n-m)^2+4 n+1\right)}\right)$$ For illustration purposes, using $m=10,n=30$, the approximation gives $460.167$ while the solution is $460.149$.

The problem is that I am unable to justify this approximation which uses the arithmetic mean.

Is there any way to justify the above approximation and (why not ?) to improve it ?

Comment: I assume you've already tried $\displaystyle\int_m^n\sqrt{x+y}~dy$.

Comment: @Lucian. Could you please elaborate ? I had a vague feeling that integration could be part of the story but I did not arrive to anything. I would really appreciate your input. Cheers :-)

Comment: Well, the sum should be “approximately” the same as the integral, which evaluates to a simple algebraic function in *m*, *n*, and *x*. The question is whether this approximation is close enough.

Comment: @Lucian. This would lead to a very complex equation, isn't it ?

Comment: It would boil down to $(x+n)^{3/2}-(x+m)^{3/2}\simeq\dfrac23x$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was meaning !! It would be a nightmare just for the approximation. What is curious is that story about the arithmetic mean. It also works fine with cube roots (even if the formula is looong !).

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer since I do not have error estimates for the inequalities below. What you have found as good estimate is exactly what is obtained from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). Since $\sqrt{x}$ is concave it gives the following result:

$$\sum_{k=m}^n \sqrt{x + k} \leq (n - m + 1) \sqrt{x+\frac{m+n}2}.$$

So using this inequality will give an approximate solution to your original problem that is too high. Since Jensen's inequality follows from concavity alone it applies to many more functions, e.g. a cube root.